# serializing structure

Tags: c++

I need to serialize my structure as binary stream. Here is how this struct looks like and how i'm trying to serialize it. I think I receive wrong values in score of my serialization. Could someone looks on it and confirm my way should work?

```
struct Termometer {
public:
  byte* address;
  uint32_t name;
  float valueC;
  uint64_t time;

  ContentPair ToFlat() {
    uint32_t objSize = sizeof(name) + sizeof(valueC) + sizeof(time);
    byte* bytes = new byte[objSize];

    uint32_t* namePtr = (uint32_t*) &bytes[0];
    namePtr[0] = name;

    float* valuePtr = (float*)&bytes[4];
    valuePtr[0] = valueC;

    uint64_t* timePtr = (uint64_t*)&bytes[8];
    timePtr[0] = time;

    ContentPair pair;
    pair.rawBytes = (void*) bytes;
    pair.size = objSize;
    return pair;
  }
};
```

With this values:

```
Termometer t;
t.valueC = 'A';
t.time = 'B';
t.name = 'C';
ContentPair content = t.ToFlat();
content.Print();
```

it gives me :

```
C000000BB0000000
```

this is struct ContentPair:

```
struct ContentPair
{
  void* rawBytes;
  uint32_t size;

  void Print() {
    char* bytes = (char*)rawBytes;
    Serial.print("Size is: ");
    Serial.println(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      if(bytes[i] == 'A' || bytes[i] == 'B' || bytes[i] == 'C')
        Serial.print(bytes[i]);
      else
        Serial.print('0');
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
};
```

Comment: And how do you "unflatten" it ? What values are you getting, using what values to send ?

Comment: @Loufylouf I posted more details

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing in `Print()`.  How, exactly, is that operation related to `Print` or serialization in any meaningful way?

Comment: Print() just show my flattened structure in byte manner. It's test method to see if score is correct when 'A','B','C' test data are using

Comment: Ok.  So where is your evidence that your serialization has gone wrong?  I mean, I see lots of things to fix in your code, but I don't see a smoking gun.  Is the reason you think something has gone wrong the lack of `A` in your output string?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I am assuming output should be C000A000B0000000

Comment: @Puchacz: Ah, well _that_ should be edited into the question then, because _that_ is your error.  The output should definitely _not_ be `C000A000B0000000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood what your test code is doing. When you assign the `float` value, for instance:

```
t.valueC = 'A';
```

You should have been suspicious about why that even compiles. The letter *A* isn't a number, after all! However, the `char` literal `'A'` *does* have a numeric value, and so the compiler is happy to silently convert it for assignment to a `float`-typed variable. Its value is (in most implementations) 65. Thus, you have assigned the value 65.0 to the `float` field of your struct.

The binary representation of the IEEE `float` value 65.0 is 01000010100000100000000000000000. (I've used the [IEEE 754 converter from Harald Schmidt](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).) In hexadecimal, that's 0x42820000. You then compare the bytes to the letters. The bytes are numeric, so the same letter-to-number conversion happens again. There is no byte with value 65 in your data, so you don't get any *A*'s in your output. However, you have two *B*'s. The first is from the least significant byte of the `date` field (because that's what you assigned to is) and the next one is from the most significant byte of the `value` field. As you can see above, the first byte has value 0x42, which in decimal is 66. If `'A'` is 65, then it's natural that `'B'` is 66.

So far, the main error in your code is one of testing — you're not seeing what you expected to see, but your expectations were wrong. You've written your serialization code. If you write analogous code for deserialization, and apply it to your serialized data, you should get the same values out that you put in. (If you *print* those values, however, you *still* won't see *A* or *B* because the default printed representations for `uint64_t` and `float` don't use the corresponding ASCII characters. Instead, you should expect to see `value == 65.0` and `date == 66`.

Answer (score 0):

The binary layout of `float` is not the same as integer types.

It is unsurprising that a `float` which contains the integer value of `'A'` will not contain a byte containing `'A'`.

Comment: Doesn't float has continuous space in memory?. I think about it as a series of bytes which are specially interpreted by CPU. So I could assign here anything. When i'm reading it as bytes, i'm assuming they will be the same as when I assign them?

Comment: @Puchacz: Float has a continuous space in memory, stored in a sequence of bytes.  You gave it a _value_, and it stored that _value_ in a _incredibly wierd_ sequence of bytes, because _floats are incredibly wierd_.    http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: `float x = 'A';` assigns the integer value of the char `'A'` to the float.  The float does not represent integer values in the same way integers do at the binary level.